# help Column formula in sharepoint list

Tags: list, infopath, excel

So i asked this question a couple hours ago:

I have made a list with InfoPath in SharePoint. All the questions are either "accepted" or "notaccepted" (radiobuttons) and I want to make a new column (in SharePoint). If someone choose "accepted", the value it gives to the list is 1, and "Notaccepted" is 2.

I want to create a new column which looks at all the columns in the list (let's say for easy sake A, B & C) and when they are all at value 1, the new column gets the value accepted, and when only 1 question is answered with "Notaccepted" ( so only one,or more, value 2) it has to say "Notaccepted".

```
So if 
A=1
B=1
C= 1

It should return "Accepted", 

When it is
A=1
B=2
C=1

it should give "Notaccepted"

If 
A=2
B=2
C=1

it should still say "Not accepted"
```

And got an answer which was

```
=IF( INT(A)+INT(B)+INT(C) = 3  ,  "Accepted" , "Not Accepted" )
```

but if they leave the radiobutton blank it get a value of "0" and shows "Not accepted". I am not that good in excel formula's but i guess it is fixable with a OR statement, which I've tried, and failed, but that's most likely because i have no clue how to make it work :p

can anyone help me out with it and make the answered formula also gives and "Accepted" if the value is 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=IF( OR(INT(A)+INT(B)+INT(C) = 3, INT(A)+INT(B)+INT(C) = 0),  "Accepted", "Not Accepted" )`

This should work.

FYI: The formula's used by calculated columns are Excel formula's and you can open a blank excel sheet to play with them :)

Comment: +1 for the Excel reminder. Saves a lot of time and frustration!